# Changing Email Passwords With cPanel XML API in PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, cpanel, whm

I've been jogging my mind on how to enable my users to change their passwords using the cPanels XML API. I've googled, played with example code, and could not find anything that remotely works. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
require_once('../includes/xmlapi.php');

$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$root_pass = 'secret';

$account = 'accountna';
$email_account = $_POST['email'];
$email_domain = "mydomain.com";

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
$xmlapi->password_auth("root",$root_pass);
$xmlapi->set_debug(1);

$args = array(
  'domain'=>$email_domain, 
  'email'=>$email_account
);


if ($xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "passwdpop", array( 'domain' => "domain name", 'email' => "user name", 'password' => "new password") )) {
    echo "Success!";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you neet to set port!
before password_auth

```
$xmlapi->set_port ( 2083 );
$xmlapi->password_auth("root",$root_pass);
```